# How to include an image for windows forms from the script's local directory

Tags: windows, forms, powershell, directory, root

I am trying to develop a lite app to run a set of powershell scripts. I have a small user base that will need to run the app. This app will have a few presentable options (scripts) that it can run from the start. The user needs to be able to click a button to run the script.

The issue I'm having is how to reference the file needed when I don't know the specific location that the user will be running the script from.

I need to be able to have a background image, and scripts stored in a small folder that will be included in the app. Is there a way to direct the script to look in the current directory for files?

Here is my code currently:

```
#Credit: Portions of this code were provided at the following URL: 

http://blogs.technet.com/b/stephap/archive/2012/04/23/building-forms-with-powershell-part-1-the-form.aspx#pi47623=2

# LOAD WINDOWS FORMS
 # Load the Winforms assembly
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")  


 #Welcome Screen: 

 #code for welcome splash here. Haven't gotten that far yet. 


 # CREATE FORM
 $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form    
 $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,400)  


 # background. This is where I need help. 
 $Image = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile("C:\Users\zstewart\Pictures\script runner.png") 

#this location is where my question arises. It won't work on another user's machine. 


 $Form.BackgroundImage = $Image
 $Form.BackgroundImageLayout = "Center"
 # None, Tile, Center, Stretch, Zoom

 #SET FORM TITLE
 $form.text = "ScriptRunner v.001"

#TEXT FIELD FOR PRINTING A RESULT
$outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,60) 
$outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,30) 
$outputBox.MultiLine = $True 
$outputBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical" #had horizontal here. Didn't work. 



 # BUTTON 
 # Create Button and set text and location
 $button = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
 $button.Size = New-Object Drawing.Point 120,30
 $button.text = "Select Script"
 $button.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 170, 100


 # INPUT HANDLER BUTTON - ON CLICK IN THIS CASE
 # Set up event handler to exit
 $button.add_click({
 Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{   
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |
 Out-Null

 $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
 $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
 $OpenFileDialog.filter = "All files (*.*)| *.*"
 $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
 $OpenFileDialog.filename
 $outputBox.text=$OpenFileDialog.filename
} #end function Get-FileName



 Get-FileName -initialDirectory "c:\fso"
 })


 # Create Button and set text and location
 $button2 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
 $button2.text = "Run Script"
 $button2.Size = New-Object Drawing.Point 120,30
 $button2.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 170,140


 # INPUT HANDLER RUN BUTTON - RUN SCRIPT
 # close button - on click close app
 $button2.add_click({
 $form.Close() #need to add code to run some included scripts. 
 })


 # ADD CONTROLS TO FORM
 $form.controls.add($button)
 $form.controls.add($button2)
 $Form.Controls.Add($outputBox) 


 # DISPLAY DIALOG
 $form.ShowDialog()
```

I realize that this is a very VERY dirty code, but I am still trying to learn as I go along. Please excuse my code skills.

Answer (score 1):

In PS v3.0 and above, you can reference the scripts directory with the [`$PSScriptRoot` automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx):

```
$Image = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile("$PSScriptRoot\script runner.png")
```

To make your script PowerShell 2.0-friendly, you could do the following at the top of your script:

```
if(-not (Get-Variable -Name 'PSScriptRoot' -Scope 'Script')) {
    $Script:PSScriptRoot = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to test this further but It appears to work. I'll just have to include a line to check for the version of powershell. Thank you again!

Comment: @ Mathias R Jessen - Thanks. That will save me some time.

Comment: @Mathias how can I Stretch the backgrounimage to Fullscreen or equal size with the main form?

Comment: @Hakikat41 `$Form.BackgroundImageLayout = 'Stretch'`

Comment: @Mathias thanks I had already figured it out, but I have it with double quotes like "Stretch"